# Using 'diff' compare usernames from file1 to file2 containing emails

Tags: linux, command-line, regex, diff, string-manipulation

I am trying to identify active accounts over dead accounts and was wondering if `diff` along with `grep` or `sed` or `regex` can be used, instead of writing a long program.

```
File1 (usernames)                  File2 (emails)
janedoe                            johndoe@email.com
johndoe                            janedoe@email.com
```

Each file contain about 1000 times and I need to do this frequently, once a week or so.

Task 
-Check if the usernames from the File1 exist in the File2. In the above sample data, they exist. 
 
-If they do exist, comment them out in File1.

In the past, I have used diff to compare files and have used regex to ignore lines. But unfortunately, I cannot wrap my brains around to ignore or a consider only a part of the string from the emails. (Since @ and anything after that is not comparable)

Any assistance would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using any script language that knows hashes/dictionaries/associative arrays/whatever it calls the feature.

A very very very simple approach would be like this:

```
$> cat File1
johndoe
janedoe
nosuchkid
$> cat File2
johndoe@email.com
janedoe@email.com
$> awk -F'@' 'FILENAME=="File2" { emails[$1]=$0; next}; { print ($1 in emails) ? $1 : "# "$1}' File2 File1
johndoe
janedoe
# nosuchkid
```

Probably, you can see that this one does not modify anything in the input files just writes stdout.

EDIT:
Redirecting the output into a file and renaming that would appear as changes in the original file called File1 here (making a backup of the original file is **always** a good idea):

```
$> awk -F'@' 'FILENAME=="File2" { emails[$1]=$0; next}; { print ($1 in emails) ? $1 : "# "$1}' File2 File1 > File1.tmp ; cp File1 File1.old ; mv File1.tmp File1
$> cat File1
johndoe
janedoe
# nosuchkid
```

EDIT2: Let's be a little less literal:

```
$> export PERSONFILE=File1 EMAILFILE=File2; awk -F'@' 'FILENAME==ENVIRON["EMAILFILE"] { emails[$1]=$0; next}; { print ($1 in emails) ? $1 : "# "$1}' "$EMAILFILE" "$PERSONFILE" > "$PERSONFILE.tmp" ; cp "$PERSONFILE" "$PERSONFILE.old" ; mv "$PERSONFILE.tmp" "$PERSONFILE"
```

Comment: But `awk` cannot write the output to the input file. Which is a necessity.

Comment: Nothings stops you from redirecting the output to a new file and renaming the new file to File1. Actually, that is what any program would do inside when working on text files where there is not a dedicated byte in the file for flag purposes.

Comment: Can you provide a solution using your answer. As I am not familiar with `awk` and its properties.

Comment: Okay, did so. Actually, for redirection and renaming, there is no other feature required than what the basic OS provides.

Comment: Can I assign the variable File1 & File2, to actual filenames or I have to type the filenames in the command.

Comment: Also, I used your command and I got empty files. Your command seems to keep the File1 and File1.old empty, no content.

Comment: I guess you gave the the mail and person file in the wrong order in the parameter list. It does matter here

Comment: So, I would be writing the command as `export PERSONFILE=usernames.txt EMAILFILE=emails.txt; awk...` and it should work? Right?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go.

Comment: I needed a slight help. Is it possible to switch the commenting option to the email file and NOT the username file. Also please don't remove the email address, just comment it out.